# Parsing a string in C programming

Tags: c

I am trying to parse a string passed in as an input parameter. Basically if the input string is under 50 characters I want to add additional zeros in the new string. If the input string is over 50 characters, just take the first 50. I am getting segmentation faults and could use a big of guidance.

Extra information: I have a struct in the beginning of the program defined as follows:

```
typedef struct Integer50
{
  int *digits;
} Integer50;
```

ParseString Function:

```
Integer50 *parseString(char *str){
     int x = 0, y = 0, temp = 0;
        int length_string;
        Integer50 *large_num;
        large_num = malloc(sizeof(large_num));
        int i;

     if (str == NULL)
        {
         return NULL;
        }

    if(strlen(str) < MAX50){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error, input string is less than fifty (50).\n");
        for(i = 0; i < MAX50; i++){
            large_num->digits[i] = str[i]; 
        }
    }
    else{
         for(i = 0; i < MAX50; i++){
            large_num->digits[i] = str[i]; 
    }
    }

    return large_num;
}
```

Comment: You have to allocate memory for `large_num->digits`

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: dynamic memory allocation with malloc

Comment: What do you have in str, i hope there no whitespaces in there. If str contains integers then is better to use strtol to convert them to integer before assigning them

Comment: did I not do it correctly when I did large_num = malloc(sizeof(large_num));

Comment: there are no whitespaces. the string input would be something like 1234567890

Comment: this `large_num = malloc(sizeof(large_num));` allocate memory for the struct not the pointer in the struct.

Comment: large_num = malloc(sizeof(large_num)); is wrong, u need to write large_num = malloc(sizeof(Integer50));

Comment: `sizeof(large_num)` is the size of a pointer, probably 4. I feel you might want a buffer of `MAX50*sizeof(int)`. If you have a buffer of size 4 bytes and then do anything which thinks of a buffer for 50 ints, then you are pretty much guaranteed an access to something far off - which causes a segmentation fault. @Seek Addo I think you mean the same, but `large_num->digits` is also a pointer.